# Multiple instances of wcf service library?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I'm building a Silverlight application using WCF service for communication. When I run multiple instances of Silverlight application does it also run multiple instances of service library or not? Also I want to know, is it running multiple instances of Silverlight if I copy  the application URL from browser and paste it into a new tab. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run multiple instances of Silverlight application does it also
>   run multiple instances of service library or not?

No, because Silverlight and your service are two differents applications. Silverlight runs on client whereas your service is hosted ins IIS. As a website, the service will expose data for all clients.

> Also I want to know, is it running multiple instances of Silverlight
>   if I copy the application URL from browser and paste it into a new
>   tab.

Every instance of Silverlight is sandboxed. Even multiples of the same Silverlight app in the same Browser page are duplicate instances and nothing is shared. They are therefore not even shared between browser tabs.